# Toggle menu but also allows click inside without closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly apologies for the random title, I really can't think of another way to word it succinctly.

This is my issue.

I have a couple of nav icons, that when clicked toggle menu displays, just like you see everywhere: facebook, etc.

When you click outside of the `div` it hides the menu.

It works but I have two problems.

1. Clicking outside works to close the open div, but clicking on the icon that triggers the toggle doesn't close it, it just re-toggles it instantly.
2. I would like to be able to click inside of the menus without them closing, which they are currently doing `onclick`.

The html looks something like this, where the `user-menu` is the click-able icon that toggles the `div` contained within.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <div class="user-menu">
    <div id="user-dropdown">MENU CONTENTS HERE</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.user-menu').click(function () {
   $('#user-dropdown').fadeToggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
   var container = $("#user-dropdown");
   if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container.hide();
   }
});
```

**FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/vo8a1r0p/

**EDIT - ANSWER**

Using a mixture of Bhuwan's answer and a `stopPropagation()` it's now working.

**Working jQUERY**

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass("user-menu")) {
    $('#user-dropdown').fadeToggle();
  } else {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass("dropdown-menu")) {
    $('#user-dropdown').show();
  } else {
    $('#user-dropdown').fadeOut();
  }
 }
});

$("#user-dropdown").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Working FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/ne4yfbjp/

Comment: please add some menu html too

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: It's all being generated by php. It will look very messy and confuse the question if I add it. If it helps the classes inside are : `username`, `atname` and an unordered list with 3 `li` elements.

Comment: I'll rustle up an html fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass("user-menu")) {
    $('#user-dropdown').fadeToggle();
  } else {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#user-dropdown").hasClass("dropdown-menu")) {
      $('#user-dropdown').show();
    } else {
      $('#user-dropdown').fadeOut();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div>
    <button class="user-menu">Menu</button>
    <div id="user-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="username">
        Some User
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, this has fixed issue number 1, but the div is still closing when I click inside of it. Here is an updated fiddle using your code. https://jsfiddle.net/d42a9oyg/1/

Comment: Okay I fixed it by adding `stopPropagation()` https://jsfiddle.net/xjg4rfqy/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: @spice you will need to add a class to the dropmenu https://jsfiddle.net/hu20ppn1/